# What are all of the registry keys of IIS features?

Tags: iis, wix

I have developed a bootstrapper-application with WiX 3.8.
This boostrapper-application includes a setup-file for the activation of the IIS-features.
For most of them i have found the registry keys and prevent the activation while my setup is reinstalling or repairing.
Normally these keys can be found under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\InetStp\Components\".

In my WiX-Setup-file i implement the check like this:

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components"
                     Value="W3SVC"
                     Variable="WebServer"/>
```

And here the ExePackage for the activation of - per example - the IIS-Webserver:

```
<ExePackage Id='IIS_WebServer'
            DisplayName='Installing IIS: IIS-WebServer'
            PerMachine='yes'
            SourceFile='.\Resources\Dism.exe'
            InstallCondition='NOT WebServer'
            InstallCommand='/Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer'>
</ExePackage>
```

But there are nearly a dozen features for which i could not verify the registry keys.
These are the features:

- IIS-WebserverRole
- IIS-CommonHttpFeatures
- IIS-ApplicationDevelopment
- NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45
- NetFx3
- IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics
- IIS-Security
- IIS-Performance
- IIS-WebServerManagementTools
- IIS-ManagementService
- WAS-WindowsActivationService

Does anybody know a document with all registry keys for ALL IIS-features?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

The list is going to be ever changing from Windows version to Windows  version and IIS version to IIS version.  Personally I don't attempt what you are doing because I don't like an application installer making OS level changes to the platform.  This goes back to the NT/2K/2003 days where you wouldn't have had the i386 bits to do it anyways.

The only thing I can suggest is use a profiling tool and/or machine snapshotting tool  to detect and map the system change when you enable each of those features.